# What is the mean of numbers that we have found?

Tags: combinatorics

The set of $Z(m,n)$ contains all the integers with $mn$ digits that $n$ digits are $1$,$n$ digits are $2$,..,and $n$ digits are $m$.For any number that is from that set we calculated the sum of $\vert{a-b}\vert$ where $a,b$ are two digits next to each other.What is the sum of numbers that we have calculated?

It is clear that for $m=1$ the sum is $0$ but for $m \ge 2$ It becomes really hard.Any hints?

Comment: For a number $a \in Z(m, n)$, let the digits of $a$ be (in order) $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{mn}$. Then the desired sum is $\sum_{a \in Z(m, n)} \sum_{i=1}^{mn-1} |a_i - a_{i+1}|$. It may be more convenient to switch the order of summation and compute $\sum_{i=1}^{mn-1} \sum_{a \in Z(m, n)} |a_i - a_{i+1}|$. The inner sum should be the same for each $i$, so you only need to count (for some $i$) the number of $a \in Z(m, n)$ such that $|a_i - a_{i+1}|$ takes on a given value.

Comment: @user125932 Could you give an answer with more explain?